# Proving $||A||=||A^{*}||=||AA^{*}||^{1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am studying functional analysis, In the lecture notes I saw the
claim:

> Let $A\in L(\mathcal{H})$ where $\mathcal{H}$is a Hilbert space. then 
>   $$ ||A||=||A^{*}||=||AA^{*}||^{1/2} $$

There is a proof in the notes that I don't understand:

> $$ ||Ah||^{2}=|\langle Ah,Ah\rangle|=|\langle
>  A^{*}Ah,h\rangle|\leq||A^{*}Ah||\cdot||h||\leq||A^{*}A||\cdot||h||^{2}
>  $$
>
> $$
>  \implies\frac{||Ah||}{||h||}\leq||A^{*}A||^{\frac{1}{2}}\implies||A||,||A^{*}||\leq||A^{*}A||^{\frac{1}{2}}\implies||A||=||A^{*}||=||A^{*}A||^{\frac{1}{2}}
>  $$

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the implications in
the second line (except the first one that $\frac{||Ah||}{||h||}\leq||A^{*}A||^{\frac{1}{2}}$
which I understand).

I really don't understand how the inequality in the second implication
was obtained, or how from the inequality I get the equality

Comment: $\|A\|^2 \le \|A^{*}A\| \le \|A^{*}\| \|A\|$, so $\|A\| \le \|A^{*}\|$. Applying this to $A^{*}$ we get $\|A^{*}\| \le \|A^{**}\| = \|A\|$, hence $\|A\| = \|A^{*}\|$. Then $\|A\|^2 \le \|A^{*}A\| \le \|A\|^2$.

Comment: @njguliyev - thanks for the comment. don't understand how you got the first inquality in your comment, but assuming it I can see how the norms of $A,A^{*}$ are the same. but even then I don't understand your last inquality, or how does it use the first implication in the second line

Comment: There appears to be an error. The $\|A^*A\|$ terms in the second line should all be to the $1/2$ power.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my previous comment. It is corrected now.

Comment: @Potato - its a typo, I will correct it. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the supremum of $\frac{\|Ah\|}{\|h\|}$ is by definition the norm of $A$. Since for all $h$, this is bounded by the constant $\|A^*A\|^{1/2}$, taking the supremum over all $h$ shows $\|A\|\le \|A^*A\|^{1/2}$. If you repeat the argument on the first line and swap the positions of $A$ and $A^*$, you get similarly that $\|A^*\|\le \|A^*A\|^{1/2}$ Multiplying these, you have $\|A^*\|\|A\|\le \|A^*A\|$. But since in the general the norm of the product is at most the product of the norms, you also have $ \|A^*A\|\le \|A^*\|\|A\|$.

It follows that $\|A^*A\|= \|A^*\|\|A\|$. In particular, both of the inequalities $\|A\|\le \|A^*A\|^{1/2}$ and $\|A^*\|\le \|A^*A\|^{1/2}$ must be equalities.